# Invalid Token in Joomla Survey

Tags: joomla, token, survey

im having some issues regarding to a survey module on this website:

www.madridactual.es -> You can find the survey at the middle right of the home page.

The problem is that sometimes when you vote you may get an Invalid Token. I have the cache desactivated and still get these issues.

What could be the problem?

Thank in advances for your help!

Comment: It's about your sessions expiring, not cache.

Comment: Even if the survey is public?

Comment: There is still a session, right?  I mean I don't know what you have in your code but that's the usual reason.

Comment: Nope, there is no session if your not logged. This website is also using sh404 which may be the issue but im not sure.

Comment: Um wow that's interesting, maybe you've never noticed the guest field in your session table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the form doesn't work means there can only be two causes.

1) session expiring, which is very unlikely since it takes 15 minutes before it expires. Also I don't think you need sessions to pass the token back and forth (it's a hidden field).

2) the cache. You say you have cache disabled (I assume in the global configuration-system tab); did you disable the cache plugin as well?

If this is the case (disabling the cache plugin works) then most likely your survey component is not injecting the Token properly: Joomla cache takes care of updating tokens for us!  But if the token is rewritten or inserted in a get call (or an ajax form) it will not be updated.  That is a design issue and it's the responbility of the extension developer.  It can be easily addressed leaving the token in its standard `<input` and handling it with javascript on the client side to inject its name/value into the ajax call.